# Imported method cannot be resolved to a method

Tags: java, import

I want to use the gravity constant, which is defined in another file to calculate the weigth of a person by multiplying it with their mass. Sadly the gravity constant "cannot be resolved to a type".
The gravity constant is defined here:

```java
package info1Classes;

public class Physics {

    static float getGravity() {
        float gravity = 9.80665F;
        return gravity;
    }
}
```

I've imported the class Physics using

```java
import info1Classes.Physics;
```

, but my method

```java
private float getWeight() {
        return (mass * (new getGravity()));
    }
```

still doesn't work.
I've read that refreshing or restarting Eclpise often resolves this error, but both of those didn't work for me.

Comment: `getGravity()` is package-private (because you didn't specify an access modifier in the method's declaration), that is, it's not visible to any class that isn't located within the same package. You also don't invoke methods that aren't constructors with the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `new` on a method, which isn't allowed. Even if it were, the member is package-private by default, so it won't be visible to your other classes outside that package.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
package info1Classes;

public class Physics {
    public static final float GRAVITY = 9.80665F;
}
```

Then in your other class you could use this to get the value of gravity:

```
Physics.GRAVITY;
```

Comment: Of course I'm assuming your gravity value will not change throughout the program, as in the case of moving this simulation to another planet. In that case, a method would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! Because I was forced to use the gravity constant as it ist, I couldn't fully adopt your solution, but I found out that I just have to add a "Physics." infront of the import. The changed code is the following, if anyone cares:  java private float getWeight() {
  return (mass * Physics.getGravity());
 }